# Spring MVC session management

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

I am totally new to Spring MVC and I m really confused regarding managing sessions. Here I m basically creating a login form and what it does is that it connect with the database and check whether the user exists and if exists, it redirects to a welcome.JSP page. Now here is my doubt, suppose I m accessing the welcome page directly without login, so what I want to do is, it should automatically redirect to the login page. I tried many methods and still the result is wrong . Plz help me out in this.

```
Here is my Code,
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String loginPage()
    {
        return "loginPage";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loggingIn(LoginDTO login,Model model)
    {
        DatabaseConnection con=new DatabaseConnection();
        if(con.loginValidation(login))
        {
            model.addAttribute("welcome",login.getUserName());
            return "welcomePage";
        }
        return "loginPage";
    }
```

Login Page:

```
<body>
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    <div class="login">

        <form action="login" method="POST">
            <label for="userName">User Name: </label> <input type="text"
                name="userName"><br> <label for="password">Password:
            </label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <p style="color: red;">${welcome}</p>
    <p style="color: green;">${success}</p>
    <p>
        <a href="newUser">New User?</a>
    </p>
</body>
```

Welcome Page:

```
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;color:blue;">Welcome ${welcome}</h1>
</body>
```

When I try to access the welcome page directly I get this,

```
HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
Type Status Report
Message Request method 'GET' not supported
Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.37
```

***What I want is, it should redirect to the login page automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement GET for “/“ mapping in your controller.